Fewest Instructions for Mihály Quine
https://mihaly.barasz.com/compressed-loop/game.html

You have a simple, line-oriented “compression” language. The language works as follows:
The document must start with the begin keyword and end with the end keyword. There are two possible commands, each identified with a single letter followed by one or two non-negative integer arguments. These are as follows:

Literal: l n — The n lines that follow this command are added to the output as is. The next command comes after that.

Repeat: r n k — The k lines of the output which start at the nth line from the current end of the output are repeated. Note, that if k > n, then some of the repeated lines will be the lines that were added by this command itself.


Your goal is to create a valid “compressed” document for which the output is identical to the input. Write the compressed document on the left, see the result on the right.

For example,
begin
l 3
foo
bar
baz
r 2 1
r 4 1
end

outputs
foo
bar
baz
bar
foo

What is the fewest number of instructions needed to realize a quine?

24 instructions
begin
l 1
begin
l 1
l 1
l 4
begin
l 1
l 1
l 4
r 4 4
l 4
r 4 4
l 4
r 4 4
l 4
r 4 4
l 4
doesn't
matter
r 2 2
end
r 2 2
end

Based on the following answer. First 17 steps found in 1 minute by a Python script by a Python script checking most combinations of instructions using arguments ranging from 1 to 5 inclusive. Fortunately it happened to spot a partial solution that I was then able to complete.
26 instructions
begin
l 2
begin
l 2
l 3
begin
l 2
l 3
l 3
begin
l 2
l 3
r 4 4
l 4
r 4 4
l 4
r 4 4
l 4
r 4 4
l 4
doesn't
matter
r 2 2
end
r 2 2
end

Based on @gsitcia's answer. Found in 2.5 minutes by a Python script checking most combinations of instructions using arguments ranging from 2 to 5 inclusive. (The script isn't infallible but fortunately the wild cards in the output it did find can be filled in consistently.)

I've also brute-forced all programs ending in the same 7 instructions using parameters from 1 to 8 inclusive and this is still the optimal answer.

I've now brute-forced all programs of up to 24 instructions using parameters from 1 to (I think) 6 inclusive and this is still an optimal answer (my script stopped at the first answer).

27 instructions
begin
l 3
begin
l 3
begin
l 3
l 3
begin
l 3
l 3
l 3
begin
l 3
r 4 4
l 4
r 4 4
l 4
r 4 4
l 4
r 4 4
l 4
doesn't
matter
r 2 2
end
r 2 2
end

Based on @programjames answer.

I brute-forced for solutions that only used l 3 3, l 3 4, and r x y where x and y ranged from 1 to 5, but my script ran out of memory. Its best solution so far was similar to this solution though.

... because it had a stupid bug and was never going to terminate. Sigh...

Having finally fixed my code, it now finds this solution in 8 seconds.

37 instructions:
begin
l 4
begin
l 4
begin
l 4
l 4
begin
l 4
l 4
begin
l 4
l 4
l 4
begin
l 4
l 4
l 4
l 4
begin
l 4
r 5 5
l 3
r 5 5
l 3
r 5 5
l 3
l 3
r 5 5
l 3
r 5 5
l 3
r 3 2
end
r 3 2
r 3 2
end

